# Split numbers and linear independence of multiplicative inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, split-complex-numbers

My understanding is that the product of *ijk* may equal +1 when working with split-quaternions. What are good examples of systems defined such that the product of two (not three) linearly independent (i.e., not *jj* or *kk*) elements of unit magnitude may equal +1? I have been poking around http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/index.html but I have yet to find/recognize the answer to my question via that resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually specify what type of algebraic structure you're considering, so let's figure it out from context:

You ask for linear independence of elements, which implies you have an underlying vector space structure. You then want to take products of those elements, so you have some sort of algebra over tha vector space (possibly non-associative). You reference the element "1" as a unit, so I'll assume your algebra is unital. You want those elements to be of "unit magnitude", so you also have some sort of norm on this algebra.

I suspect the general category you want to be asking about is [Clifford algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra). In any case, my example is from the complex numbers, which should be an allowable space no matter what additional requirements come up.

If $z,w$ are two elements from your algebra, and you want $z w = 1$, that means that $z$ and $w$ are units and are inverse of each other. And for any reasonable definition of "magnitude", you should be able to scale your answer so that both of the elements are of unit magnitude.

So to turn your question around, you're asking for an element of your algebra that is linearly independent from its inverse. There are many examples, perhaps the simplest being the primitive cubic roots of unity $z = -1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2$ and $w = z^2 = -1/2 - i\sqrt{3}/2$. They are linearly independent, of unit magnitude, and inverses.

Edit: Additional requirements have now been added: The system should be a finite dimensional unital normed algebra over the reals (the vector space has to be over a field, so it can't be over the non-negative reals), $z$ and $w$ must have no real part (in other words, ${1, z, w}$ must be linearly independent), and $z$ and $w$ must have $+1$ as a coefficient (with respect to what generating set it is unclear, since they will always have $+1$ as a coefficient in any basis of which they are members).

With these additional requirements, I believe no example exists. Let's take a *slightly* stronger version of your question and suppose that we're in a [composition algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/composition+algebra), which only additionally assumes that the norm comes from a non-degenerate quadratic form (all of your named examples so far are composition algebras). From every such composition algebra, you can define a symmetric bilinear form $\langle v, w \rangle$ that gives rise to the norm, as well as a conjugate $\bar{v} = 2 \langle v, 1 \rangle - v$. In particular, when $v$ "has no real part", that means that $\langle v, 1 \rangle = 0$, and so $\bar{v} = - v$. But we also have from Prop 2.7 on my linked page that when $N(v) = 1$, $v^{-1} = \bar{v}$. Putting these two requirements together gives that $v^{-1} = -v$, and thus, $\{v, v^{-1}\}$ can never be linearly independent. Thus, no such $j$ and $k$ can exist in such an algebra.

So if there are *any* examples, you would need a finite dimensional unital normed algebra over the reals where the norm doesn't come from a quadratic form, which I think will not look sufficiently close to the "systems" you're considering. (Depending on how you define "norm", there might be none at all.)

Comment: Thank you for helping to clarify the question. I am specifically curious regarding which systems (if any) may be capable of satisfying =+1 such that  ≠  without  or  having a real part while  or  have only +1 as coefficients (e.g., if *jk* of a system like the split-quaternions equalled +1 instead of -i).

Comment: Your notion of "system" is still imprecise and undefined. Did you look up the terms I gave in my answer to figure out what sort of algebraic systems you're considering? I suspect you want a (possibly) non-associative finite dimensional unital normed algebra over the real numbers.

Comment: In any case, I think you're eventually going to add a requirement like "$j$ and $k$ must be part of a minimal generating set for the algebra but also $jk = 1$." This condition is inconsistent, since $k = j^{-1}$ and so can't be part of a minimal generating set if $j$ is already part of it.

Comment: Finally, I'll point out that "have only +1 as coefficients" is a misleading condition as well, since coefficients will change if you change your generating set. Asking that they have "real part 0" is also implicitly asking that 1 is an element of your minimal generating set of the algebra.

Comment: Yes: finite dimensional unital normed algebra over the nonnegative reals; doesn't need to be non-associative. What prompted you to consider the requirement of minimal generating set? It hadn't crossed my mind but I am interested in how you made the conceptual connection.

Comment: You can't have an algebra over the nonnegative reals since those don't form a ring. As for minimal generating sets, you seem very motivated by the "defining generators" of say, the quaternions or split-quaternions, and if I respond with an answer of elements in some algebra you know (like, say, the split-quaternions), but the elements are linear combinations of the more familiar basis, I imagine you might cry foul. (Since you're already thinking in terms of "coefficients" with respect to this standard basis.)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your new requirements.